# Clash Royale How and Where to Find Free and Open Tournament List

Tags: clash-royale

Please read my question before you say it's duplicates.
I think many of you have the same problem as I do. As the clash royale has not implemented search or filter function to the tournament tab, there isn't anyway that you can find an open tournament.
Based on others answered questions, it seems like betting on luck by trying different key words is the way, but the truth is the odds are not in my favor. Not to mention trying to figure out the password to a password protected tournament. 
Anything helps.

Comment: I'd recommend against posting your previous information as an answer; it seems borderline spam.

Comment: Please specify how I did post any thing as an answer.@Frank

Comment: I didn't say you posted it as an answer.  I recommended *against* you posting it as an answer, because it's borderline spam.

Comment: http://howsmyclan.com/OpenClashRoyaleTournaments/

Answer (score -1):

I did my research and the best way to find a tournament is to follow certain streamers, clans or social platform channels. Here is one that I found on Twitter, his name is 15Ktourney and he/she hosts free 120 cards tournament everyday. Will update for more info.